# How to create an ordered array from values that have an order number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So I have a series of strings, which contain and image path and order # concatenated.

They look like this:

```
const images = [
  'photo1.jpg,0'
  'photo2.jpg,2'
  'photo3.jpg,1'
]
```

So the correct order should be: photo1, photo3, photo2.

What I need to do is process this into a correctly ordered array with just the path values. So ultimately I need:

```
const orderedImages = [
  'photo1.jpg'
  'photo3.jpg'
  'photo2.jpg'
]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: is the order indicator zero based and is it continuing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array.sort` to order them and `array.map` to remove order value.

```js
const images = [
  'photo1.jpg,0',
  'photo2.jpg,2',
  'photo3.jpg,1'
]
var output = images.sort(function(a,b){
  return +a.split(',')[1] - +b.split(',')[1]
}).map(function(item){
  return item.split(',')[0]
});

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split the values and assign to the given index.

```js
var images = ['photo1.jpg,0', 'photo2.jpg,2', 'photo3.jpg,1'],
    array = [];

images.forEach(function (a) {
    var aa = a.split(',');
    array[aa[1]] = aa[0];
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, sort the element with help of **[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** and then update the elements using **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method.

```js
var images = [
    'photo1.jpg,0',
    'photo2.jpg,2',
    'photo3.jpg,1'
  ]
  // sort the element
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    // split the element and calculate 
    // return value based on that
    return a.split(',')[1] - b.split(',')[1];
    // iterate and generate new array with updated value
  }).map(function(v) {
    // generate array elemnt by removing the number part
    return v.split(',')[0]
  })


console.log(images)
```

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
var images = [
  'photo1.jpg,0',
  'photo2.jpg,2',
  'photo3.jpg,1'
].sort((a, b) => a.split(',')[1] - b.split(',')[1]).map(v => v.split(',')[0])


console.log(images)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```js
var images = [
  'photo1.jpg,0',
  'photo2.jpg,2',
  'photo3.jpg,1'
];
images.sort(function(a,b){
   return Number(a.split(",")[1]) - Number(b.split(",")[1])
});
var orderedImages = images.map(function(item){
  return item.split(",")[0];
});
console.log(orderedImages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) and simply write:

```
var orderedImages = _(images)
  .sortBy(function(element) { return element.split[','][1] ; })
  .map(function(element) { return element.split[','][0]; })
  .value();
```